# Java - Reset iterator values in a loop

Tags: java, loops, reference, iteration

So I've never known much about how Java iterators/iterables/iterations work, and every once and awhile I'm hesitant on how to do something. This is one of those times.

I have a list of objects, and I need to change each one. But as I have to literally reset each reference in the list, I'm not sure how to do this. I came up with this implementation that would make it absolutely certain to work:

```
for (Object obj : new ArrayList<Object>(list)) {
    list.remove(obj);
    list.add(change(obj));
}
```

Note that I cannot just do this:

```
for (Object obj : list) { change(obj) }
```

because due to the nature of `obj`, I cannot modify it in place. `Change()` returns a new object that is changed.

Basically, I'm asking if this will be ok:

```
for (Object obj : list) {
    obj = change(obj);
}
```

or if I have to use the top implementation.

Comment: Just create a new list and fill it with the changed objects. No need for tricks with the iterator. Or use the set method like Paul Vargas suggested.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the next:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    list.set(i, change(list.get(i)))
}
```

The *javadoc* for the method [**`public E set(int index, E element)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-) in [**`java.​util.​List`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) states:

> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element (optional operation).

Comment: You are fantastic. However, it would be 
`for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
 list.set(i, change(list.get(i)))
}`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid making a copy of the list, the best way is to use a ListIterator:

```
for (ListIterator<Object> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Object obj = it.next();
    it.set(change(obj));
}
```

The advantage over the solution that uses `get(i)` and `set(i)` is that it's O(n) whatever the type of the list. Accessing elements by index on a LinkedList is very inefficient.

Comment: `get(i)` and `set(i)` are O(1). The internal implementation of an `ArrayList` is an array. You are right on a `LinkedList`, but I am using an `ArrayList`.

Comment: That's the point. If in 6 months you decide to use a LinkedList instead, the above iteration will still be as efficient as it could be. That's the whole point of using iterators. Note that you're not saying anywhere in your question that your list is an ArrayList.

Comment: Well I technically do say that it's an ArrayList, but I see your point. However, in my case, I am never going to be making this list a LinkedList. In general, however, your way is probably best.

Comment: Nitpicking: what you technically say is that you create a *copy* of the list (which could be any kind of list), and that this copy is an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Object obj : list) {
    obj = change(obj);
}
```

Would not work because you are only changing a local variable reference, not the reference that is in the list.

Comment: Yea, that's what I thought.